# How to filter a range of data where the data is not equal to the input ID in google sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, filter

[image]

Hi everyone,

I have a range of ID data in column B. Column D is where I can give my input. I want column F to print the ID in column B whenever the ID is not appear in the list of column D. So based on the example in the screenshot above, column F will only have 21 output ID by excluding ID `1007`,`1001`,`1019`,`1021`,`1018`.

I'm trying to use `=FILTER($B$4:$B$29,B4:B29<>D4:D29)` and `=QUERY(B4:D29,"Select * where B is not D",0)`, seems like both are not working well. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
=FILTER(B4:B, countif(D4:D8,B4:B) = 0)
```

Comment: Yes, this is perfect! Thank you!